# Windows batch command to delete files from a folder except one file

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am trying to create a batch script to move a set of files from one folder (root) to another and delete files of extension `.dll` in the *root folder* except one file. The command I tried is able to copy but not delete the files.

```
MOVE D:\mpgdata\sync\*.txt D:\data\sync\QDB_TXT_FILES

for %%i in (d:\data\sync*.dll) do if not "%%i"=="work.dll" del /f  "%%i"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It had a case sensitive compare.  `/i` fixes that.
There was also a missing backslash.
The `%%~nxi` makes it compare the filename only.

```
MOVE "D:\mpgdata\sync\*.txt" "D:\data\sync\QDB_TXT_FILES"

dir d:\data\sync\*.dll /b
pause

for %%i in (d:\data\sync\*.dll) do if /i not "%%~nxi"=="work.dll" del "%%i"
```

Comment: Thanks. But its still not working. Also I am able to do it when placing the specific batch file in the particular folder

d:\data\snc
with the code

for %%i in (*.ack) do if not "%%i"=="SN.ack" del /f  "%%i"

Hope, the problem is in referring to the location

Comment: sorry to mention its still not working . Since its working in the specified folder, I guess there is a mistake in the location specification.

Comment: I added an echo command before the del so it should echo the commands to the screen and then pause.  See what is printed.  If nothing is printed then check d:\data\snc to see if any DLL files are there.  Another point - is the folder meant to be `snc` or `sync` in two places?

Comment: Hi, the *.dll is not getting populated in the batch file during runtime from the specified location. The dll s are available in the specified location. The same is able to be seen while running the batch in the same location 'd:\data\sync' in which the location is not specified. But the batch file cannot be placed there.
corrected the mistake its sync folder.

Comment: I changed the code above again.  See what it prints to the screen.  If there are DLL file there then it will show them.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. The mistake was not including the double braces "d:\data\sync\*.dll", but the problem now exists is work.dll is getting deleted ,since it compares to "d:\data\sync\work.dll" to "work.dll"

Comment: The double quotes are only needed if the folder path is different from what you showed us it is.